# Creating Rows in ListView with ArrayAdapter in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an app that's getting information from an API request and then displaying a list of devices. After several hours of combing through documentation, I cannot figure out how to format the View that is created from the `ArrayAdapter`. Essentially, if the device has an error, I want to display a red circle to the right of the button and display a green button if there is no error.

`deviceList` is the name of a ListView that I am trying to display my list of buttons inside of. `deviceNames` is an array of strings that contains the names of the devices.

The TextViews that are created are also clickable, which is what the `onItemClickListener` is handling. This section works, but I wanted to leave it in because I do need the buttons to start an activity that displays device-specific information.

Ideally I would like to essentially create a template that I can just change the values of the text and the color of the indicator for

Below is my code:

```
                    // List of device names
                    val listView: ListView = findViewById(R.id.deviceList)
                    val arrayAdapter1: ArrayAdapter<*>
                    arrayAdapter1 = ArrayAdapter(
                        this@Homepage,
                        R.layout.device_button,
                        deviceNames
                    )
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1)

                    listView.onItemClickListener =
                        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
                            val pos = position
                            println(pos)
                            val device = jsonArray.getJSONObject(pos)
                            val ID = device.get("id") as String
                            println(ID)
                            goToDeviceDetail(ID)
                        }
```

Below is the XML file for `device_button`. I tried to add formatting here and essentially create a template for a button that would allow me to change the text and the color of the indicator, but it got mad that it wasn't just a TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#25383C"
    />
```

Below is the button that I would like for it to look like. I'm likely going to just make the background a solid color rather than the image that is in the below picture:

[image: Example of what I want the button to look like]

Answer (score 0):

I would say the biggest problem is your using a simple API for a more complex problem. It is entirely possible do it with a `ListView` and `ArrayAdapter`. But I would highly recommend looking into `RecyclerView/RecyclerView.Adapter`

The way it works out is...

`RecyclerView.Adapter` binds your list of data ie Devices to the individual `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

The `ViewHolder` would inflate your xml layout that contains the button. You then have access to all `View` contained in that layout easily.
You then can put listeners on the button.

The `Adapter` then can be setup to receive new data, when received it can rebind the data that has changed.

Say the user clicks one of the device buttons it does a task. When it gets back it will say hey `Adapter` I have a new List for you.(The list now contains the "fixed" device).

`ViewModel`*(contains observable data)*->`Fragment/Activity`*(Observers the data)*->`Adapter`*(Receives the data)*->`ViewHolder`*(Displays the data)*->`Activity`*("Fixes the data")*->`ViewModel`->...loops

Here is a very good example.

https://medium.com/@atifmukhtar/recycler-view-with-mvvm-livedata-a1fd062d2280

If you really want to keep using the `ListView` and `ArrayAdapter` you are receiving the clicked view here.

```
    OnItemClickListener {
          /*Parent of the view*/ parent,
          /*The view clicked*/ view, 
          /*position of data*/position,
          /*id of the view clicked*/ id 
       ->{
             view.findById(R.id.text_view);
             //onClick  
         }
    }
```

With that you know what has been clicked so you know what has to be changed later when you get back from your other `Activity`.